# Drupal: what's the similar way of views_embed_view() for embeding a Panel page?

Tags: drupal, view, panels, drupal-ctools

i use to use `views_embed_view` API function to load views automatically. now i need to load a panel content problematically; but i could not find a function like `views_embed_view`.

is there such a thing at all?

is there something like `panels_embed_page` or is it related to **ctools**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do something like that with panels, nor that you will ever be able to do it.

Panels pages can be a lot more complex than views, with all the context handler and other stuff that goes on behind the scene. You best bet will be to add the panel panes instead. But then you will be more or less back to using views anyways.